# Is it possible to have multiple OS Installers on one USB Drive?

Tags: boot, usb

I want to have many operating systems(windows and linux) installers (not installations) on one bootable USB drive.

For an example some OS installers I would like to have on that one USB drive

- Windows 8 Enterprise 64bit
- Windows 10 Preview 64bit
- Windows 10 Preview 32bit
- Ubuntu Server 14.04 64bit
- Ubuntu Desktop 14.04
- ...

Would this be possible?

**I obviously(?) want to boot from this USB drive**

Comment: Why would you think you would not be able to do that?  If you are talking about only installers, just put each one in a separate folder or partition.

Answer (score 0):

Also Isostick provides a hardware based solution.  It is a memory stick with a virtual CD/DVD that you can mount ISO(s).  You do need a separate microSD card, but I have one and it works fine.